# Concurrency control when storage is in files (not database)

Tags: c#, concurrency, notifications

I need to architect and implement a multi-user application in C#, in which the persistence layer consists of files - and not a database. The files will be in a shared filesystem accessible for read/write to all clients of the application. So the problem of concurrency control and data consistency arises. If the storage layer was a database, the database vendor would have taken care of this headache, but now in a file-based storage how do I ensure data consistency in a multi-user environment? And also, if one client changes the data in a file, how does another client that may have already opened the file gets notified. Could you please point me to resources that will help me solve these issues. Thanks

Comment: Difficult to diagnose without understanding the domain. What are the disbenefits of losing concurrency? Also, why can't you use a db?

Comment: You could force exclusiveness per file, there are various ways to do that.

Comment: Not so sure I'd be keen to base a multi-user solution off files. As architect, do you have the ability to...suggest alternative designs?

Comment: You cannot guarantee data consistency without a tool.  Windows doesn't properly handle shared files for data consistency.  You could create your own tool (probably a service to handle the application), but why reinvent the wheel.

Comment: The domain is petrophysics and each file represents data for an oil or gas well. So user A loads up data for well 1 and while he is looking at it user B loads up the same well and makes changes in the data he sees there and saves it back. There are legacy reasons why persistence layer cannot be a database and needs to be a set of files

Answer (score 0):

You can try [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileSystemWatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
And implement Reader-Writer Lock pattern. When someone wants to read data, they open it for read only with sharing read, quickly read, then close and listen for changes if needed. When someone wants to write data - open file with write access without sharing.